# Call application method from embedded Tomcat/Jetty jsf-bean

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm trying to develop an application that embeds tomcat or jetty with JSF.
Is it possible to make a call from a jsf-bean to a method of the application that embeds and started tomcat?

If it isn't possible, what would be a good way of communication between the application and the servlet container?

I haven't found anything in the docs, google or even on stackoverflow.com! But I'm sure there is a solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The question is not clear enough. Is it so that there is already a servlet container in which you are hosting the JSF application and within this JSF application you are again starting an embedded jetty ?

Comment: No. The servlet container should be embedded in an application. And within the servlet container runs the webapp using Java Server Faces. The question is about a way of communication from the webapp/JSF-bean back to the application that embeds and starts the servlet container. I was thinking about using ActiveMQ. If there is no way of doing so, I don't know why it should ever be necessary to embed a servlet container?? What would be the advantage (Whole-in-one product?)?

Comment: Embedded servlet container are never meant to be invoked from UI, its main usage is for testing. Use a main method to start your embedded container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveMQ would be a overkill for this scenario. You could simply start a RMI registry in the main application and host some remote interfaces with the APIs you need to communicate between your application and the jsf webapplication.